# How to set proper type for PouchDB document content without using any

Tags: typescript, pouchdb

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
const db: PouchDB.Database<Config> = new PouchDB(process.env.POUCH_REMOTE);
const orgs = [{login: 'username'}];
interface Config {
  members: string[];
  config: {
    irc: {
      server: string
      port: number
      nickname: string
      ident: string
      realname: string
      NickServPass: string
      channel: string
      sasl: {
        cert: Buffer | string
        key: Buffer | string
        key_passphrase: string
      }
      bindhost: string | null
      requireAuth: boolean
      notice: boolean
    }
    attentionString: string
    multipleCommitsMaxLen: number
    detailedDeletesAndCreates: boolean
  };
  repos: {
    [key: string]: {
      enabled: boolean
    }
  };
}

let orgDB: any; //<-- Need to use type `any` here, so we don't get those darn messages
for await (const org of orgs) {
  try {
    orgDB = await db.get(org.login);
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.name === 'not_found') {
      db.put({ _id: org.login });
      orgDB = await db.get(org.login);
    }
  }

  const members: Array<{login: string}> = [{login:"user1"}, {login:"user2"}]
  for (let { login: member } of members) {
    if (!orgDB.members!.includes(member)) { //<-- Here the used before assignment happens
      orgDB.members!.push(member); //<-- Here the used before assignment happens
    }
  }


  const repos: Array<{full_name:string}> = [{full_name:"repo1"},{full_name:"repo-new"}]
  for (let repo of repos) {
    if (!orgDB.repos[repo.full_name!]) //<-- Here the used before assignment happens
      orgDB.repos[repo.full_name!] = { enabled: true }; //<-- Here the used before assignment happens
  }
  db.put(orgDB); //<-- Here the used before assignment happens
}
```

How do I specify the proper type for the variable that contains the document from PouchDB?

If I use the default type inheritance from the typings, I always get `Property 'x' does not exist on type 'IdMeta & GetMeta'.`.
Now when I use the typings I created and the `PouchDB.Database` interface,  and go try to push a new document to the db, I get the inverse message, that the property is missing.

I wish to use the proper types instead of `any`, since it isn't the best. Any ideas or work-arounds?

Comment: I tried your code and removed the `any` type annotation and made up my own `Config` interface (since you didn't provide yours), and I don't get an error.  Please add sufficient code to the question to reproduce the error(s) you are talking about.  You can copy your code snippet to another folder and install the necessary node modules to test that the code reproduces the error before posting it.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the interface. I might add that this only shows up in my editor (VSCode with TSLint plugin) and nowhere in TSlint or `tsc` output.

Comment: Okay, so that error seemed went away and can't reproduce, but the question is still the same. this is the new message i get `Type '{ _id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Config'` when i use db.push(). And further along in my code, it thinks that I have used the `orgDB` variable before defining it, which is not correct

Comment: Your `Config` interface declares `members`, `config`, and `repos` as required properties, and you have declared that the database contains documents of type `Config`, so you get an error when you try to insert a document that doesn't contain the required properties.  Did you perhaps mean to use optional properties, or can you say more about the scenario?  If you'd like help with the "use before definition" error, please add the relevant code to the question.